# How to change value of span from Ajax using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a span and a element.

My Code like;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var spanValue=$("#num1").text();
$("#num2").keyup(function(e) {
        $("#num1").html((spanValue.replace(/,/g, '') - $(this).val().replace(/,/g, '')).toLocaleString('en'));
    });
});

type();
function type() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "fetch_data.php",
            method: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#type").html(data); **is something to change?**
            }
        })
    }
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="type">
    **span element will show like → <span id="num1">1,000</span>**
</div>  
<input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Num2" class="form-control number" id="num2" autofocuum2s>
```

I expect the calculation will do properly. My span value does not change. Is there need to change in Ajax or in jQuery.

Expect like:

1. If typed 20 in textbox , the span value will be: 980 (1,000-20=980)
2. If backspaced or deleted 0 in textbox : the span will be → 998 (1,000-2=998)

Comment: Can be clear what the exact problem is?  You seem to be asking if you need ajax - your code works fine without the ajax:  https://jsfiddle.net/07h6zaxg/  if the ajax call is to set #num2 from fetch_data.php, then after `$("#type").html(data)` add `spanValue = $("#num1").text()` - as noted in @JarodS answer, you don't update `spanValue`

Comment: @freedomn-m I have a problem that when type one digit and delete it. It will not show original value in span. my case from ajax.. type 1 → 999 (expect 1000)

Comment: So you have 1000, you type 1 and you expect... 1000?   Your expect in the question matches what your code *already does*:  https://jsfiddle.net/07h6zaxg/

Comment: This code contains multiple errors and design flaws.  The selected answer does not fix the larger problems.

Comment: From the description, the selected answer *causes* the problem that isn't there in the first place.   So it's very unclear what the problem is/was.

Comment: I got it. It works properly in Ajax block;
$.ajax({
            url: "fetch_data.php",
            method: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#type").html(data);
                var spanValue = $("#num1").text();
                $("#num2").keyup(function() {          
                    xxxxxx
                });
            }
        })

Comment: There is no need to add in $(document).ready(function() {xxxxxx}

Answer (score 1):

The value of your variable "spanValue" is never being updated after the page is loaded, because it is outside of the keyup function. So it gets set when the page is loaded, and remains that value even when something else is typed in.

If you swap lines 2 and 3 so that the value is updated on every keyup, you should see the span change.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#num2").keyup(function(e) {
        var spanValue=$("#num1").text();
        $("#num1").html((spanValue.replace(/,/g, '') - $(this).val().replace(/,/g, '')).toLocaleString('en'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe that part of OPs code works - they don't want a "running" total, but rather 1000-[num2] as num2 changes.  Though your description of the issue is correct if OP is updating #num1 from ajax - they need to reset spanValue after changing #type (incl #num1) in the ajax success.